# How to setup Apache to allow PUT/POST/DELETE request to a .JSON file

Tags: json, apache, rest

I'm now working on a web front-end application. It's using RESTful API to talk to the server, doing a lot of GET/PUT/POST/DELETE requests. To speed up my development. I save some of the JSON response into a .JSON file on my dummy server. So when I run a request in development mode, the front-end will fetch those .JSON files instead of doing a real request to the server. This can speed up my development and reduce the overload of our server. However, it works only for GET requests. If I do the PUT/POST/DELETE requests, it always return 405 Method not allowed status code. How can I config my Apache to allow PUT/POST/DELETE request to those .JSON files?

Answer (score 3):

I too was having trouble with Apache and DELETE, POST, and PUT methods.  I however, was getting a 403 Forbidden response instead of a 405.  I added a **RequireAny** directive to an **.htaccess** file and all seems to be okay now.

```
<RequireAny>
    Require method DELETE GET POST PUT OPTIONS
</RequireAny>
```